# Can't find jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, homebrew

Jekyll was running just fine a couple days ago. I can't figure out what changed or understand the error. How can I fix this mess probably caused by me?

```
jekyll -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  2: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
  1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in 
`activate_bin_path'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in 
`find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem jekyll (>= 0.a) with executable 
jekyll (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Here's my setup on Mac 10.13.5 High Sierra:

```
Computer:~ me$ brew -v
Homebrew 1.6.9
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 69b9; last commit 2018-06-29)
Computer:~ me$ brew list
autoconf    libyaml     pkg-config  readline    ruby-build
hugo        openssl     rbenv       ruby
Computer:~ me$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
Computer:~ me$ which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
bundle -v
Bundler version 1.16.2
Computer:~ me$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]
Computer:~ me$ gem -v
2.7.7
```

Comment: It must have run off to hyde.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `bundle install` from within the directory of your Jekyll site?

From what you've pasted:

`` `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem jekyll (>= 0.a) with executable 
jekyll (Gem::GemNotFoundException) ``

It seems you're trying to install a non-existing version.